# factory pattern, need to know the actual implementation type?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-4.0, factory-pattern

Im trying to write the results from a SProc to a textfile. I have 3 scenarios:

1. SProc takes no parameters.
2. SProc takes parameters.
3. SProc takes parameters and there is a loop which increments the parameters.

scenario 1 and 2's data will be stored in a list since they are most likely to be just a single row of results.

scenario 3's data will be stored in a data table.

I was thinking of using the factory pattern for this, 3 different classes each implementing a specific interface, and a factory to determine which of the 3 would be required.

The issue is once the method is finished and the completion event has been risen, i need to know what scenario was implemented (datatable vs List) Is this an issue? If so, could someone please explain why + a possible solution?

Note: Just to clarify, this is not a plea of, please write my program.

Thanks very much for your time, i appreciate it.

Comment: If all you want is writing the results to a text file, file expose the list or data table at all? You could simply pass the file name to the method and let the method write the data to the file. Or you could pass an object to the method that the method should write its result to.

Comment: @dtb getting the method to write to the file instead of the event handler is a very good point. Not sure why i didnt think of that. If thats the case then would the factory pattern still be applicable. Im assuming yes since i would no longer need to know what implementation was carried out? Thanks for ur help!

Comment: I don't know your requirements, so I can't tell if you need a factory or not. You also might want to have a look at the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you need to know an actual type behind an interface, you might have chosen a wrong point to introduce the interface. This is what it looks like here.

It looks to me like you want to separate the concern for doing your logic (which produces some data) from the logic of logging the results (in this case to a text file, but there might be other targets, right?). Why not introduce an interface for ResultLogging?

```
interface IResultLogger
{
   void LogList(List<Something> data);
   void LogDataTable(DataTable data);
}
```

and pass an instance of this interface to all your methods doing the logic?

If you don't want to have the "logging" (calling the IResultLogger interface) inside these methods, you might add another abstraction: The concept of "ResultData".

```
abstract class ResultData
{
   abstract public void LogToResultLogger();
   //add methods to access the data in a way you might need for other things in your program
}
```

and derive a "ListResultData" and "DataTableResultData".

I don't see the value of the factory pattern here.

Another way of doing it would be to have a

```
class ListLogger
{
   public void LogList(List<Something> data) {}
}
```

and

```
class DataTableLogger
{
   public void LogDataTable(DataTable data) {}
}
```

and do

```
void method1() and method2()
{
  //do logic
  new ListLogger().LogList(data);
}

void method3()
{
  //do logic
  new DataTableLogger().LogDataTable(data);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. No the whole point of the program is just to execute the selected SProc and write the results to the file. Im sorry but im not sure i completely follow. "and pass an instance of this interface to all your methods doing the logic?". So i would need to declare the interface, Construct a class which implemented it. Then, as u said, pass the instance to each of the 3 separate methods and hard code it such that if scenario 1 or 2 are run, they call the LogList, otherwise LogDataTable is executed?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. If it seems ok to have the 3 methods call some logging, then I wouldn't say it's a problem that you need to "hard code" which method is being called, because the 3 methods need to know which type of data they have, so they can also know which method to call for logging this data.

Comment: but am i not having to write 3 complete methods, therefore in method 1 and 2, i can just write logResults.LogList(data); In method 3 i can write logResults.LogDataTable(data); where logResults is the instance of the class which implements the interface. Or have i misunderstood?

Comment: correct, that's what you can do. Or see my alternative solution in the answer.

Comment: cool i think thats should allow me to complete this today. Thanks very much for your help.